# How to delete several folders at once in GIT

Tags: git

Hi pushed to repository several solutions. Unfortunately, I didn't setup .gitignore.
At the moment my repository stores dozens bin/Debug and Obg/Debug folders.
Is there a way to delete them at once ?

Answer (score 1):

If only one commit is affected, then `git rm` the files, then create your `.gitignore` then `git add -A; commit --amend --no-edit` then `git push --force origin master`. **Warning:** `--force` can break things for collaborators, but if no-one pulled your commit yet, then it should be okay.

If there are multiple commits you should look at [this guide](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/).

In the above answers I assumed you wanted to save disk space. If that's not an issue, then just simply `git rm` the files, add them to `.gitignore` and create a new commit.

Answer (score 0):

```
find ./ -name Debug | xargs rm -rf     
git add --update    
git commit
git push
```

After there command, those files will not been tracked by git any more.

Comment: `rm -rf` combined with output from other commands is really dangerous. You should probably run `find ./ -name Debug` first and check the output, or leave out the `f` flag so it will ask for confirmation.

Comment: @Leventix you are right,  confirmation before deleting will be safer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> ... At the moment my repository stores dozens bin/Debug and Obg/Debug folders.
>   Is there a way to delete them at once ?

---

Before answering let's understand how does git handle committed content in order to  understand what need to be done.

Every time you execute a `git add` git calculate the SHA-1 of the file and start to track it from this point on.

Every time you execute a ***`git commit`*** the content is added to git and **from this point on git** `track` **any changes made to this file**.

If you decide to add this files to ***`.gitignore`*** at this time it will have no effect, since as explained before git will continue to track the content.

---

### ***`How to tell git not to track commited content?`***

As explained above, once content is committed to the repository git will continue to track it.

At this we need to decide in which way we wish to fix it:

1. Leave the wrong content in git
2. Remove the content from git history

---

### ***`Leave the wrong content in git`***

This is the simple case, we will simply delete the track content from git and since the file is deleted and is already in the `.gitignore` it will not be tracked from this point on

```
# add the content to git ignore
# delete the content from git (not from file system) and commit it
git rm --cached <files..>

git commit -m "Removed files..."
```

---

### ***`Remove the content from git history`***

This part is bit more tricky and risky and you **several options** as well.
Read this post: ***[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716)***

Very detailed with a walkthrough for each option on how to fix it.